# How to get compile time error checking with real valued function arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible use static_assert (or something similar) with function arguments that are real valued?  What I am trying to do is the following. The arguments **min** and **max** will always be constant in my application.  Ideally, I would like to use them as template parameters, but doing so isn't possible because they are real valued.  The motivation for using static_assert is that I would like to get compile time error checking.

```
template <typename counts_t, typename real_t>
real_t counts2real(counts_t c, real_t min, real_t max)
{
  constexpr real_t cmin = std::numeric_limits<counts_t>::min();
  constexpr real_t cmax = std::numeric_limits<counts_t>::max();
  constexpr real_t cdelta = (cmax - cmin);

  // ERROR: non-constant condition for static assertion.
  static_assert(max > min, "max > min");

  real_t delta = (max - min);
  real_t p = (c - cmin) / cdelta;

  return (p * delta + min);
}

int16_t x = 0;
const float min = 10.0;
const float max = 5.0;

float xf = counts2real<int16_t,float>(x, min, max);
```

Comment: have you tried defining `min` and `max` as `constexpr` ?

Comment: What is the definition of "real value"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `float`s cannot be used as template parameters, `float const&`s can. Thus, you can pass `min` and `max` as template parameters:

```
template <typename real_t, real_t const& min, real_t const& max, typename counts_t>
real_t counts2real(counts_t c)
{
  constexpr real_t cmin = std::numeric_limits<counts_t>::min();
  constexpr real_t cmax = std::numeric_limits<counts_t>::max();
  constexpr real_t cdelta = (cmax - cmin);

  static_assert(max > min, "max > min");

  real_t delta = (max - min);
  real_t p = (c - cmin) / cdelta;

  return (p * delta + min);
}
```

Usage:

```
constexpr float min = 10.0;
constexpr float max = 50.0;

float foo(int16_t x) {
    return counts2real<float, min, max>(x);
}
```

Changing `max` to `5.0` results in a diagnostic as desired:

```
<source>:13:21: error: static assertion failed: max > min
   static_assert(max > min, "max > min");
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/i5cX1-)

---

In C++17, you can avoid having to specify the type of `min` and `max`:

```
template <auto const& min, auto const& max, typename counts_t>
constexpr auto counts2real(counts_t c)
{
  ...
}

// ...
float foo(int16_t x) {
    return counts2real<min, max>(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for info.  I need to study templates more.  C++17 is unavailable to me.  As an aside, if I include iostream, using namespace std, and add a main routine that uses foo and prints the output, compilation again fails.  Excluding the using namespace std fixes the issue.  I wonder why?

Comment: @fuse117 I wouldn't be able to tell unless you gave an MCVE. For instance, a Compiler Explorer link. However, it seems likely that the `min` and `max` constants are conflicting with `std::min` and `std::max`

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  Its only really an issue in some toy/test code, so I am not concerned about it.  It won't effect my real application.  Thanks again.